# как проводить валидацию xml используя jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

Приложение на spring + jaxb

jaxb разбирает входящую xml и парсит ее в объект перед вызовом методов контроллера.
Затем jaxb модель преобразую в строку и прогоняю через валидатор с использованием xsd.

Как настроить валидацию jaxb так, чтобы он не по своей неведомой схеме валидировал поля перед тем как их распарсить в объект, а по моей xsd, которую я ему подсуну.

контроллер:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {"application/xml"}, produces = {"application/xml"})
    public String add(@RequestBody user user,
                      @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String id) {
        String result =  service.add(id, user);
        return result;
    }
```

jaxb молель:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    @Size(max = 36)
    private String id;

    @Size(max = 1024)
    @XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
    private String value;

    @Size(max = 5)
    @XmlElement(name = "Type", required = true)
    private String type;

    @Size(max = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "name", required = true)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "date", required = true)
    private String date;

    @Size(max = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "name", required = true)
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Ответил на аналогичный вопрос тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059232/%d0%92%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-xml-%d0%bf%d0%be-xsd-%d0%b2-restcontroller-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e/1059629#1059629