# Валидация xml по xsd в RestController и выдача ошибок пользователю

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, xsd

есть схема xsd

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Purchase" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:long" name="id"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="count"  />
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="lastName"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="age"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="amount"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="purchaseDate"/>
                <xs:element name="purchaseItem">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:long" name="id"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

есть контроллер который принимает xml и записывает в базу объект

```
   @RequestMapping("/save")
    public void savePurchase(
            @RequestBody Purchase purchase
            ){
        purchaseRepo.save(purchase);
    }
```

сам класс Purchase

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Purchase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Integer count;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private LocalDateTime purchaseDate;
    @ManyToOne
    private Item purchaseItem;
}
```

нужно перед записью в базу данных провести валидацию xml файла по xsd схеме если все ок- записать ,если нет выдать пользователю почему не прошло

Answer (score 0):

Доработайте следующий пример:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "person", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public String getPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return person.toString();
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Data
@ToString
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import java.io.IOException;

@Service
public class PersonConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Person> {

    private final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    public PersonConverter() {
        super(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(Person.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected Person readInternal(Class<? extends Person> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(PersonConverter.class.getResourceAsStream("/person.xsd")));
            jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
            return (Person) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputMessage.getBody());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException(e.getMessage(), e, inputMessage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Person person, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(person, outputMessage.getBody());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

`person.xsd` в `resources/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```